# Ranking rows according some number

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have table like this

```
 id    | name
----------
1      | A
2      | B
5      | C
100    | D
200    | E
201    | F
202    | G
```

I need ranking rows from `1 to 3 order by id`, that is, I need result:

```
 id    | name | ranking
---------------------------
1      | A    | 1
2      | B    | 2
5      | C    | 3
100    | D    | 1
200    | E    | 2
201    | F    | 3
202    | G    | 1
```

How to make this?

P.S.

I am trying:

```
 SELECT  id, name, row_number() OVER( order by id RANGE  BETWEEN 1 AND 3 ) AS ranking FROM t
```

This gives syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANGE` is actually used for something else:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Try using a modulus instead:

```
SELECT  id, name, 1 + (row_number() OVER( order by id ) - 1) % 3 AS ranking
FROM t
```

Comment: ... alas, `RANGE` is not yet supported by PostgreSQL either, at least in 9.3 and older. Real pity, there've been a bunch of times I'd have found it quite handy.